# The minimum of $F(u)=\int_0^1 |u'(x)-u(x)| dx$

Tags: inequality, optimization, integral-inequality

Let $C=\{u\in C^1[0,1]\mid u(0)=0,u(1)=1\}$. What is the minimum of the functional 
$F(u)=\int_0^1 |u'(x)-u(x)| dx$.

What I guess is that the minimum is attained when $u(x)=x$.

What follows is my try.
Let $C_0=\{u\in C^1[0,1]\mid u(0)=u(1)=0\}$. For any function $u\in C$,one has $u-x\in C_0$. Then we only need to consider the minimization of 
$$
\int_0^1|v'(x)-v(x)-x| dx=\int_0^1|x+v(x)-v'(x)| dx
$$
over $C_0$. But, I do not know how to process further.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. That is great.